# Why do console.log and document.write output different results?

Tags: javascript, console.log, document.write

I have the following code:

```js
let size = 8;
let board = "";

for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
      board += " ";
    } else {
      board += "#";
    }    
  }
  board += "\n";
}

console.log(board);
document.write(board);
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center; color: rebeccapurple;">Chess Board</h1>
```

`console.log` output:

[image]

`document.write` output:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Why do they output different results?

Comment: `document.write` makes changes to the `DOM`, and doesn't recognize `\n` (a new line character in JS) as an HTML line break. You need to use `<br>` to see a line break in HTML

Comment: Btw, don't ever use `document.write`... Use `console.log` for debugging and `.textContent`, `.innerText`, or if you absolutely need to, `.innerHTML` to display text in the document.

Comment: If you want the browser to render whitespace as the occur in the source then use a `<pre>` element or set the `white-space: pre;` CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

the Document interprets html. " " and "\n" is not HTML code.
You should use `"&nbsp;"` and `"<br/>"` instead of " " and "\n"

```
for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) {
      board += "&nbsp;";
    } else {
      board += "#";
    }    
  }
  board += "<br/>";
}
```